# Proper way to spawn a gameobject that grows in scale from 0 to 1

Tags: unity-game-engine

The menu system in the game I'm working on has a "pop" animation where it grows from scale 0 to scale 1 when it spawns.  When the player gets a game over, the menu is instantiated and then the "pop" animation is triggered, causing the menu to pop in from the center of the screen.

This works fine most of the time. However, sometimes the menu will appear for a single frame at full size after it's instantiated. Then, the animation gets triggered which causes it to snap back to scale 0 and grow back to scale 1.

I've come up with a workaround for this which is to save the menu prefab at scale 0, so when the menu is instantiated it's already at scale 0 before the animation begins. **The downside to this is that when I'm working on the menu in the editor, I have to go back and set the scale of the menu to 1 so I can work on it and then remember to set it back to 0 when I'm done.**

Is there any way around this?

---

As seen below, the Game_Over_Open ("pop") animation sets the scale to 0 on the first frame.

[image: Pop Animation Screenshot]

Here is the animator that controls the "pop" animation.  There are actually 2 different animations that need to be called based on a condition, so I cannot set this animation to be the entry state. Instead, the entry state is an empty state I have labeled as "Idle."

[image: Animator Screenshot]

I tried setting the scale of the menu to 0 in the `Awake()` of the menu script, but that did not fix it. There is still a single frame where the menu appears at full size.

Comment: Where is the code that does the scaling located?

Comment: @BenRubin The menu prefab has an `Animator` component which handles the scaling when it's spawned.

Comment: How about putting something in the menu's `Awake()` that sets its scale to zero as soon as it's instantiated?

Comment: @BenRubin I gave it a shot but unfortunately the behavior is the same.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have the first frame of your animation set to scale it to 1?

Comment: @BenRubin Yes I'm sure. I will add a screencap to my question for confirmation.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have some other code settings the scale to 1?  Try putting a `Debug.Log` in `Awake` and `Update` to print the current scale, and make sure it's starting from 0.

Comment: @BenRubin I was able to solve the issue by setting the entry state of the menu animator to an animation that did nothing but set scale to 0. Previously the entry state had an empty animation and was there just so I could call the pop animation later. The reason I did not have the pop animation as the entry state is because there are 2 pop animations I have to choose from based on a condition. I'm still confused as to why that would work when setting the scale to 0 in `Awake()` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by setting the empty "Idle" entry state of the animator to an animation that set the scale of the menu to 0 on the first frame.